# VSTO Excel Com Add In Ribbon Not Loading

Tags: c#, excel, com, vsto

I'm using VS 2010 to develop an Excel 2007 COM Add-In. Because it's a VS 2010 Office Project, it targets the .NET 4.0 Client Framework. I've added a new Ribbon (XML) item called MyRibbon, so default filenames of ThisAddIn.cs, MyRibbon.cs, and MyRibbon.xml.

Everything builds fine. It publishes with a .vsto extension. When I install the add-in (via the provided Setup.exe) it takes in Excel as being installed, and is checked in the COM Add-Ins list. It also is designated to load on start up. However, either opening Excel first or opening an Excel file does not add the tab to the ribbon.

I can tell the Add-In loads because it puts "COM add-in loaded" in the first cell of the first sheet. It appears as though CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject() is not getting called.

Does anyone have any ideas, or could tell me how to display any error messages that might be getting buried?

Details below.

I've added the override of CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject():

```
protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new MyRibbon();
        }
```

MyRibbon.xml looks like this, three buttons in a group inside of a tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="TabAdvComTracking" idMso="TabAdvComTrackingMso" label="Adv.com Tracking">
        <group id="groupPrepare" label="Prepare">
          <button id="GenerateNewWorkbook" idMso="GenerateNewWorkbookMso" enabled="1" size="large" onAction="GenNewWorkbook" label="Make"  />
          <separator visible="1"/>
          <button id="ClearData" idMso="ClearDataMso" enabled="1" size="large" onAction="ClearData" label="Clear" />
        </group>
        <group id="GroupDoIt" idMso="GroupDoItMso" label="Just Do It">
          <button id="CaptureIds" idMso="CaptureIdsMso" enabled="1" size="large" onAction="CaptureData" label="Eat" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

MyRibbon.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace AdvComTrackingAddIn
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyRibbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

        public MyRibbon()
        {
        }

        #region IRibbonExtensibility Members

        public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
            //ribbonID when loaded into Excel should be Microsoft.Excel.Workbook
            return GetResourceText("AdvComTrackingAddIn.MyRibbon.xml");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Ribbon Callbacks
        //Create callback methods here. For more information about adding callback methods, select the Ribbon XML item in Solution Explorer and then press F1

        public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
        {
            this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        }

        public void GenNewWorkbook(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            Excel.Workbook newWorkBook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Add();

            Excel.Worksheet newWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)newWorkBook.Worksheets.Add();
            newWorkSheet.Name = "DBTS " + GetDateRange("MMDDYYYY");


        }

        public string GetDateRange(string format){
            string day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
            int offSet = 0;
            if(day == "Sunday") offSet = 1;
            else if(day == "Monday") offSet = 0;
            else if(day == "Tuesday") offSet = -1;
            else if(day == "Wednesday") offSet = -2;
            else if(day == "Thursday") offSet = -3;
            else if(day == "Friday") offSet = -4;
            else if(day == "Saturday") offSet = -5;

            DateTime MondayStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(offSet);           

            return MondayStartDate.ToString(format) + "_" + MondayStartDate.AddDays(4).ToString(format);                
        }

        public void ClearData(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            Excel.Sheets wksheets  = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets;
            Excel.Worksheet sheet;

            for(int i = 0; i < wksheets.Count; i++){
                sheet = wksheets[i];
                if(sheet.Name.StartsWith("DBTS")){
                    sheet.get_Range("A6:H12").Clear();
                    sheet.get_Range("A16:D22").Clear();
                    sheet.get_Range("A26:D10000").Clear();
                }
                else if(sheet.Name == "Advisory.com Activity"){
                    sheet.get_Range("A4:B10000").Clear();
                    sheet.get_Range("D4:F10000").Clear();
                    sheet.get_Range("H4:J10000").Clear();
                }
                else if(sheet.Name == "Unique Hits Per URL"){
                    sheet.get_Range("A4:E10000").Clear();
                }
            }            
        }

        public void CaptureData(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
        }

        #endregion

        #region Helpers

        private static string GetResourceText(string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resourceNames = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (string.Compare(resourceName, resourceNames[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNames[i])))
                    {
                        if (resourceReader != null)
                        {
                            return resourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Finally, ThisAddIn.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AdvComTrackingAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.get_Range("A1").Value = "COM add-in loaded";
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }

        protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new MyRibbon();
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove your override of CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject.  By default, this is implemented by ThisAddIn's base class, and calls CreateRibbonObjects.  You can either override CreateRibbonObjects (this should return an array of all of your Ribbon objects), or just let the default implementation of CreateRibbonObjects do its thing (which is to say, reflect over the entire assembly everytime that your addin starts up).

You can read more about how all of this ties together in this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004110917/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/03/vsto-performance-ribbon-reflection.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem. I had an incorrect path to the XML file and it was returning empty:

```
 public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
 {
    return GetResourceText("CheckThisIsTheCorrectNameSpace.Ribbon.xml");
 }
```

Hard coding a Namespace as a string is not a good idea, mainly because they are not refactor-able as well as the helpful comments below.

Comment: This is indeed a pitfall, because the code is hidden in a collapsed region "IRibbonExtensibility Members" by default. I first dismissed this answer, thinking that I did not have this function in my Ribbon.cs file, but indeed I had. When I renamed my ribbon, the hardcoded path in this function had not been automatically updated. So if others are wondering why their ribbon does not show up, this is worth looking at.

Comment: This helped me find why an xml ribbon wasn't loading after I migrated from a legacy WinForms style ribbon, where the previous developer had shared the ribbon across multiple add-ins by adding the source files via a linked reference. With that approach the ribbon xml is not returned as a resource.

Comment: If you move code into folders, make sure the namespace in GetCustomUI() is updated as per Jerry Thompson's note above.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem when trying to change the default TabAddIns.
What i see is that idMso is for office bar tabs and id is for new tabs.
The following works for me.

```
<tab id="TabAdvComTracking" tag="TabAdvComTracking" label="Adv.com Tracking" visible="true" insertAfterMso="TabAddIns">
```

Comment: Excellent information. In my environment, various plugins were already implemented. The new VSTO plugin must be inserted after the default add-ins tab.